# Should you write $a_1^2$ or ${a_1}^2$?

Tags: notation

- *I originally posted this on TexStackExchange, but someone advised me to post it here.*
- *I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate, but I have looked and found no similar question.*

---

We consider a $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, and we want to square the first component $a_1$.

I read a long time ago that the correct way to do that is to write

```
{a_1}^2
```

which transforms into

[image]

instead of

```
a_1^2
```

which transforms into

[image]

But someone just told me that everybody writes

```
a_1^2
```

so it is not a good idea to write otherwise, to avoid confusion with others.

> Considering this, what would be the best way to write it according to you?

Comment: I write $a_1^2$ all the time. I'm not really conscious about it, especially when reading, so I can't say that I've explicitly noticed what other people do, though. I guess that's an argument for "It's up to you, as long as it's readable and reasonably unambiguous".

Comment: You should consider more general exponents, like $a_1^{22222222222222222}$. Then the first seems better.

Comment: Use $\left(a_1\right)^2$. Always.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter either way, its pretty obvious what you're indicating regardless of which way you write it.

Comment: Like $a_1^{{a_2^2}^2}$